# cant generate sign apk

Tags: android, passwords, keystore, keytool

I can't generate signed apk with android studio 2.1.3 after installing new windows 10.

I have my password and I'm sure the password is correct but when I try to generate signed apk I get this error:

> Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

for checking if my password is true or not I downloaded `Android_Keystore_Password_Recover_1.07.jar` from [here](https://maxcamillo.github.io/android-keystore-password-recover/) and after trying recover my password I got this message:

> Start dictionary attack on key!!
> Current Pass:  || est. 0 Pass/Sec
>
> Got Password in 0 seconds
> Password is: ********** for alias grammar

(I replaced my real password with **********)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

just download Signapk.zip and unzip wherever you wish, paste your apk inside the signapk folder.

open cmd / terminal , change directory to signapk folder

```
java -jar signapk.jar testkey.x509.pem testkey.pk8 test.apk test-signed.apk
```

copy and replace with you existing file name (test.apk) and output file (test-signed.apk )

[signapk.zip][1] https://github.com/ahamedansaf/Signapk/

Comment: Hi @aha I want to generate above files(x509.pen pk8 file) Do you know how to generate those files ? I am facing issue in generating signapk.jar